# How do I access the forge object from the main web view when window.location has replaced it with a 3rd party site?

Tags: trigger.io

A trigger.io blog post states:

> You can load content from the trusted_urls directly into the main view of your app by specifying the window.location. JavaScript in that page can make use of Forge APIs.

I can't find anything else in the documentation in reference to this.

I want to load a trusted, 3rd party URL using `window.location` to replace the main web view, then interact with native modules from that 3rd parties javascript. I expected that I coudl access the `forge` object but it's `undefined` within any javascript from the loaded 3rd party site.

Answer (score 0):

It's strongly recommended that you NOT use a 3rd party URL within the main view.

In general, if you want to host 3rd party sites it is best to embed them within an iFrame on your index.html page and use HTML5 messaging to marshall communication between the two pages.